# Properly handle cleanup of the static HTREEITEM

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview, code-cleanup

I have a main window with a treeview control. I need to track certain changes of a checked item, so I have decided to make a `static HTREEITEM` variable to store that handle.

I do not know if setting variable to `NULL` in my `WM_DESTROY` handler will suffice, or do I need to do something else?

Here are the code snippets that illustrate my dilemma:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HTREEITEM LastCheckedItem;

    // Other parts of the code that work well

    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            LastCheckedItem = NULL;  // or should I do something else ?

            // ...
```

Thank you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree view should handle cleanup of the individual items when it receives the `WM_DESTROY` message, and you probably don't need to set `LastCheckedItem` to `NULL` unless you need to check its value later on.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do any tidy up. When you destroy the tree view it will destroy all of its items.

Comment: Upvoted. Sorry for not accepting officially but member *user657267* was first. Thank you. Best regards.